# ayuda Django Mezclar 2 tablas y renderizar en template

Tags: django

Estoy teniendo un problema al continuar desarrollando un proyecto en django el cual consiste en hacer test de preguntas...

me he visto con la necesidad de utilizar 2 tablas de mi models.py una tabla Pregunta y otras tabla Opciones, el problema es que no consigo obtener el resultado de ambas, y además me muestra un error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

os muestro mi codigo a ver si podeis echarme una mano para entender que está fallando y como puedo solucionarlo... gracias!

Models.py

```
class Pregunta(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    textopregunta = models.CharField('Texto pregunta', max_length=1000)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.textopregunta   

class Opcion(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    correcta = models.BooleanField('Opcion Correcta')
    opcion = models.CharField('texto de la opcion', max_length=500)
    puntuacion = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    pregunta = models.ForeignKey(Pregunta, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.opcion
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^test/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.TestDetail.as_view(), name='run'),
```

views.py

```
class TestDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Pregunta
    context_object_name = 'pregunta'
    template_name = 'html/prueba.html'

    def get_queryset(self): # Devuelve un iterable con la lista de elementos que forman parte del controlador
        return Pregunta.objects.filter('textopregunta')
```

html prueba.html

```
{% block content %}    
    {% for test in pregunta  %}

    <p>Pregunta: {{ pregunta.textopregunta }}</p><br/>
    <p>Opciones: {{ opcion.opcion }}</p>

    {% endfor  %}

{% endblock %}
```

He estado consultando la documentación y he encontrado este fragmento, que creo que es donde se produce la mezcla de tablas... pero no lo entiendo.

```
<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

también tengo dudas si debo utilizar una detailview o listwiew, porque quiero ver el contenido de un test en particular obtenido a traves de su id en la template anterior...

espeor que podais enseñarme mis errores, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Crea un método en el modelo que te las opciones de la pregunta:

```
  class Pregunta(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
     textopregunta = models.CharField('Texto pregunta', max_length=1000)
     test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def __str__(self):
           return self.textopregunta   

     @property
     def get_opciones(self):
         return Opcion.objects.filter(pregunta=self)
```

Y en la plantilla

```
{% block content %} 
      <p>Pregunta: {{ pregunta.textopregunta }}</p><br/>
      {% for opcion in pregunta.get_opciones  %}
            <p>Opción: {{ opcion.opcion }}</p>

      {% endfor  %}

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta... desconocía el método empleado en el models, pero a pesar de ello, no me funciona, cuando cambio la template y accedo a ese apartado me devuelve simplemente Pregunta: no me saca nada el bucle for
¿Debería cambiar en mis views el return? es algo que no entiendo bien como funciona

Comment: Tienes las opciones relacionadas con las preguntas? Te debería de funcionar. No tienes nada que hacer el view, el método que has creado vuelve en parte del objeto pregunta